# USB midi protocol understanding

Tags: c, usb, midi

I have a sound processor device with MIDI interface over USB. I would like to control the device from my PC besides the official app to the device. However I don't have the command protocol description.
I could get managed to dump a couple of USB packets to the device with the help of usbmon. They look like:
0x0B 0xB0 0x00 0x00
0x0C 0xC0 0x05 0x00

If I send this command from my app, then the device activates program no 5.

The protocol seems to be MIDI, but if I follow it and try to interact with another functions of the device, I get no desired result.

So, I am looking for any help to get it working. For example I need to learn how to select an effect or control the volume and another parameters.

Regards,
Dmitry

Comment: Which OS do you want to use? Doesn't the device show up as a MIDI port?

Comment: That is Linux. I am not sure if it is recognized, the OS is quite limited. I would prefer to use low-level access on the protocol level from my user app to reduce dependencies from the OS.

Comment: Does it show up in the output of `amidi -l`? If not, show the output of `lsusb -v` for this device.

Comment: What do you mean with "limited"? The USB MIDI driver is part of the kernel.

Comment: amidi -l shows an empty line (with a header)

Comment: I was actually wrong about amidi. Now it shows me my device, and I can send same command to it with amidi -S. But the issue is the same - I don't see any reaction to another MIDI commands like volume change. The device is Zoom G3X sound processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find what you need in the [Universal Serial Bus Device Class Definition for MIDI Devices](http://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/midi10.pdf) and the MIDI specification.

Your example consists of two packets, each containing a MIDI event. They can be decoded as follows:

```
cable: 0
event: control change
channel number: 0
controller number: 0 (bank select)
controller value: 0

cable: 0
event: program change
channel number: 0
program number: 5
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot for a rapid answer. Your interpretation is absolutelly right. I have started from the spec to decode the commands. However, I cannot get from the spec how shall I buld the command if I like for example to set a certain value of the main volume. As I understood it should look like 0x0c 0x07 0xXX 0x00. But my device does something wrong instead setting the volume to XX. Have I bult the message correctly, or I need another message to send prior to it? Again many thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm just tried to send this message to the device, but have seen no reaction... The volume still remains at its old value. Perhaps I need to send some another event after this one?

Comment: in the other words. Do I understand it right, that the message 0x0B 0xB0 0x07 0xXX should lead to some change immediately, or it needs any additional message to be sent afterwards as in my original sequence?

Comment: This is the correct way to change a channel's volume. Whether your device (whatever it is) reacts to this message is another question.

Comment: Oh, let me ask from the other hand, just to understand the protocol sequence better.

If I need to operate with a certain Pedal. Do I understand it right, that with the command 0x0B 0xB0 0x04 0xXX I will only select a certain Pedal controller, and then I need to use Program Change event to operate with a certain Pedal?

Comment: Page not found :(

Answer (score 0):

The Zoom G3X device uses the [standard USB MIDI protocol](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/midi10.pdf).

However, just because it uses MIDI messages does not automatically imply that you know what these messages mean.
There are additional standards, such as General MIDI, but when the device is not a 'normal' synthesizer but an effect processor, most standard messages would not make sense.

To find out what MIDI messages the device accepts, look into the documentation.

If the messages are not documented (like in this case, where the device was meant to be used only with the supplied software), you have to do the changes on the device, and record any MIDI messages that it sends out (with `amidi --dump`, or `aseqdump`).

If the device does not send out messages to show changes in its current status, you have to capture the messages sent by the official app with a USB monitor (like `usbmon` in Linux).